# Comparison of Operator Topologies for Banach Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, and $L(X,Y)$ is the space of all bounded linear maps between $X$ and $Y$. I have seen in numerous places that in terms of $L(X,Y)$, the weak operator topology is weaker than the strong operator topology, and both of which are weaker than the norm topology.

I have seen this relationship proved in the context of Hilbert spaces ([Relationship between different topologies of bounded operators on a Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631355/relationship-between-different-topologies-of-bounded-operators-on-a-hilbert-spac) or [Comparison of Bounded Operator Topologies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005795/comparison-of-bounded-operator-topologies/3005865#3005865)) or in terms of kernels ([Strong Operator Topology vs Weak Operator Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470137/strong-operator-topology-vs-weak-operator-topology/4470197?noredirect=1#comment9369822_4470197)).

However, in Folland's text he states

> These topologies are best understood in terms of convergence: $T_\alpha \rightarrow T$ strongly iff $T_\alpha x \rightarrow Tx$ in the norm topology of $Y$ for each $x \in X$, whereas $T_\alpha \rightarrow T$ weakly iff $T_\alpha x \rightarrow Tx$ in the weak topology of $Y$ for each $x \in X$. Thus the strong operator topology is stronger than the weak operator topology but weaker than the norm topology on $L(X,Y)$.

I fail to see how the above definitions of convergence imply the conclusion. Can anyone show the inclusion order of these topologies strictly in terms of convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topologies of function spaces are often described in terms of convergence. For example, the [compact-open](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) can be described in terms of uniform convergence whenever the underlying space has a uniform structure.

You should know about how weak convergence is so-called because it is much weaker than strong convergence: for example, in any separable Hilbert space, the orthonormal basis vectors weakly converge to $0$ but do not strongly tend to $0$. In $L^2$, the functions $\chi_{[n,n+1]}$ tend to zero weakly but not strongly.

$T_\alpha\to T$ in the SOT iff. for all $x\in X$ and all $\varepsilon\gt0$, there exists $A$ such that $\|(T_\alpha-T)x\|\lt\varepsilon$ for all $\alpha\gt A$. This can be seen by inspecting the basis. The convergence occurs in the WOT iff. for all $x,\varepsilon$ and for all continuous linear functionals $\psi$, $|\psi((T_\alpha-T)x)|\lt\varepsilon$. These are, fixing $x$, precisely the definitions of $T_\alpha x\to Tx$ strongly and $T_\alpha x\rightharpoonup Tx$ weakly; since strong implies weak but not the other way round, these are (in infinite spaces) strictly stronger and weaker conditions. Then if we assert that this should be true for all $x$ we get $T_\alpha\to T$ strongly and $T_\alpha\leftharpoonup T$ weakly as strictly stronger and weaker conditions, and the different topologies topologise the respective notions of convergence. However, the SOT is still “weak” in that the norm topology on $L(X,Y)$ is stronger: that topologises *uniform* convergence, since it requires that the maximum value of the difference $(T_\alpha-T)$ be bounded for *all* $x$, with the same bound.

I hope this interprets your question correctly. If you want a clear example, consider $X,Y=\ell^2$ and let $T_n((x_k)_{k\in\Bbb N})=x_n$, which is a continuous linear operator. $T_n\rightharpoonup0$ weakly, so, in the WOT, and also in the SOT, but not in the norm topology.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very helpful. The only point that is still unclear to me is how convergence in the WOT implies convergence in the SOT.

Comment: Also, it is clear to me that the convergence in the SOT implies norm convergence. However, intuitively I can't help but picture that a stronger convergence property would imply more open sets in the topology. I must have a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: To your first comment, it is unclear because it is false! SOT converges implies WOT convergence but not visa versa (as demonstrated by my simple examples) @CBBAM

Comment: Furthermore, norm convergence implies SOT convergence **but not the other way round**. Strong convergence implies, in a sense, fewer open sets, since it is more difficult to be in a neighbourhood.

Comment: For example, my examples of $T_n$ in the context of $\ell^2$ converge in SOT as well (I made a mistake) but not in norm

Comment: Is there anyway to show this directly from the definitions? As in, how does $\|(T_\alpha - T)x\| < \epsilon$ for fixed $\epsilon$ and $x$ imply $|\psi((T_\alpha - T)x))| < \epsilon$ for all $\psi$ in the dual?

Comment: I thought the problem is, for example taking the norm and SO topologies, the norm topology has too many open sets and is thus harder to converge. Wouldn't this imply it is in fact easier to be in a neighborhood, just that there are too many of them?

Comment: Each $\psi$ in the dual is normed. $$\begin{align}|\psi((T_\alpha-T)x))|&\le\|\psi\|\cdot\|(T_\alpha-T)x\|\\&\le\|\psi\|\cdot\|T_\alpha-T\|\cdot\|x\|\end{align}$$If $T_\alpha\to T$ in norm then all quantities tend to $0$; if $T_\alpha\to T$ in the SOT then the middle and first quantities tend to $0$; if $T_\alpha\to T$ only in the WOT, we cannot in general conclude anything further (the inequalities are not reversible) @CBBAM

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! So if I have understood everything correctly, $|\psi((T_\alpha - T)x)| \leq \|\psi\| \cdot \|(T_\alpha - T)x\| \leq \|\psi\| \cdot \epsilon$, since we assumed convergence in the SOT. Because $\psi$ is assumed to be in the dual, it is bounded, and so $|\psi((T_\alpha - T)x)| \rightarrow 0$. Is that right?

Comment: Ya @CBBAM This shows SOT convergence --> WOT convergence where $\psi$ bounded is essential to obtain these inequalities.

Comment: I think everything is clear now. I must have been overlooking the fact that since $\psi$ is in the dual it is necessarily bounded and so we get convergence as desired. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @CBBAM You're welcome!